# php connecting mssql db to display chinese characters

Tags: php, sql-server

I am building a php website connecting to mssql database. In visual studio, I can read normal chinese characters; but when calling data into the php pages, the chinese characters could not be displayed and resulted in strange codes.

On the other hand, when I type chinese characters in the php pages, I can read them. Therefore, I believe it is related to charset when connecting to mssql db. The following are my codes in the db connect file:-

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "XX";
$myPass = "123";
$myDB = "my_db"; 

$s = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

mssql_select_db($myDB, $s);

$set_charset = 'UTF-8';
mssql_query($set_charset, $s);
?>
```

Is there anything wrong on my codes? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the [SQLSRV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995063%28v=sql.10%29) driver instead of mssql. Or even better the PDO_SQLSRV extension; [it uses utf-8 as the default encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8
>  Data is in the UTF-8 encoding. This is the default encoding.